# VBA to sum values between two rows based on a "Identifier" in the rows

Tags: excel, vba, dynamic, excel-formula, sum

To start off just want to make it clear that  I'm new to VBA, formulas I'm reasonably good with however.

I'm creating a budget that is based around groups of campaigns with sub activities under each. I then need to sum up each sub activity into the top line for each campaign they belong to.

```
        A             B          C          D       E       F
 1 Campaign Title  Identifier  Activity     Jan      Feb    Mar
 2  Campaign 1      Primary
 3  Campaign 1      Sub        Advertising  200             300
 4  Campaign 1      Sub        Promotion             300
 5  Campaign 1      Sub        PR           100
 6  Campaign 2      Primary
 7  Campaign 2      Sub        Advertising                  500
```

So for every row where there is a "Primary" in column B, the sheet would then automatically sum up the row values in columns D,E,F up until the next "Primary" line and add the total in the top primary line. So D2 = SUM(D3,D4,D5) , D6 = Sum(D7).... etc.

Now if the sheet was fixed I would just add Sum(D3:D5) for example to each primary row and drag across, but this is going out to multiple people with different amounts of activities who will be inserting any number of campaign and sub activities which guarantees they'll make mistakes having to add the sum formulas.

I'm hoping there's some magical VBA that will automatically add in the sums if a line has primary in it, and dynamically know to have them go up till the next "primary" line?

Comment: Will "Campaign Title" always be grouped by like values, or can there be "Campaign 1" further down the sheet than in your example?

Comment: Have you tried `Pivot Tables` see sample 
  [1]: http://i.stack.imgur.com/VdGRW.png

Comment: Hi, grouping each sub under the same campaign identifier is the the goal, so yes all the campaign 1's should remain together and not be split (i'm also trying to automate this so so the sheet auto populates "Campaign title" for each sub depending on what the above primary line's campaign name is.

Answer (score 0):

1. Select columns E:G.
    
   [image: half_sums_1]
2. Tap <kbd>F5</kbd>, click <kbd>Special</kbd>, choose 🔘 **Blanks** then click <kbd>OK</kbd>.
    
   [image: half_sums_2]
3. The blanks are selected with E2 as the [ActiveCell](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff193314.aspx). Put in this formula,
    
        `=IF($C2="primary", SUM(E3:INDEX(E3:E9999, IFERROR(MATCH("primary", $C3:$C9999, 0)-1, MATCH("zzz", $C3:$C9999)))), TEXT(,))`
4. Finish with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Enter↵</kbd>.
    
   [image: half_sums_3]

Comment: Hi, thanks for this. The principle works but the sheet will be constantly used as a running budget with the user changing and updating the months and adding lines and this method unfortunately leaves the formula sitting in the cells. Ideally I'm looking at two scenarios, 
1) to create a button linked to a macro that will sum up the subs to the appropriate primary or
2) Because the user has selected "Primary", excel automatically sums up any sub values linked to that primary.